# Django: `Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains`

Tags: django

I am creating an image sharing website....

PROBLEM 1:
here is a screen shot of the search page of images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdNx4.png)
The problem here is, when I search by tag, there is an error message: `Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains`

PROBLEM 2: here is a screen shot of the upload page of an image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZzR7.png)
The problem is, I can only pick tags but not input new tag here. I want it to be able to let uploader of image to input at most 10 tags....

Here are my codes:

models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name


class Image(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery,  blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.FileField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '-' + self.description

    def regions_changed(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['instance'].tag.count() > 1:
            raise ValidationError("You can't assign more than three regions")


class ImageTag (models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

filters.py

```
class ImageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    description = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    tag = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'category', 'tag']


class NullFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['upload_date']
```

views.py

```
class ImageCreate (CreateView):
    model = Image
    fields = ['category', 'title', 'photo', 'description', 'tag']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user.profile
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

image_form.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'imagebank/form-template.html' %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```